# Queue a callback directly into an event queue

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, event-loop

In javascript, is there a way to queue a callback function directly into an event queue instead of setTimeout with 0 as a second argument?

Comment: I don't think so, it's kind of the point of the event queue isn't' it? even setTimeout will wait for following, synchronous actions to finish first. `setTimeout(() => console.log('first'), 0)
console.log('second')` will print 'second', then 'first'. Webworkers execute in a separate queue, maybe they can help?

Comment: @Jorg see my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the browser you can use [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) or [`requestIdleCallback`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/requestIdleCallback):

```
requestAnimationFrame(() => console.log('Browser is repainting'));

requestIdleCallback(() => console.log('Browser has run out of things to do'));
```

In Node.js you can use [`process.nextTick`](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/):

```
process.nextTick(() => console.log('Next tick in the event loop'));
```

Note: `requestIdleCallback` is fairly new at the time of this answer, so [check browser compatibility](https://caniuse.com/#feat=requestidlecallback) before using it in your application.

Comment: Cool, I like it

Comment: so... requestAnimationFrame is prioritized somehow? Or does it just execute on the first tick

Comment: The browser repaints itself at a standard refresh rate (60fps is common). `requestAnimationFrame` queues your callback to execute right before the next paint cycle runs. You can't insert your callback before other callbacks that have been queued in the same way, but it's not dependent on any kind of timeout period, so it should happen very quickly.

Comment: Wasn't aware the browser used `requestAnimationFrame` itself. Cheers

Comment: @Jorg it's not so much that it uses it directly, but rather provides it as an interface to allow you to synchronise your updates with the render cycle.